# Редирект файлов библиотеки

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, редирект

Друзья, столкнулся с такой задачей
**Есть** 
1.  Локальный сайт на OpenServer (стоит на Windows Server) – путь расположения \server1\site1. Сайт стоит на  Drupal 7
2.  Файловое хранилище (жёсткий диск с сетевой картой) – путь расположения \server2\
3.  Библиотека книг, прикреплённая к сайту 1, находится по адресу - \server1\site1\files\

**Нужно** – в целом перенести библиотеку книг с адреса \server1\site1\files\
На адрес \server2\,  чтобы

**Что  было сделано**
В корне сайта в файле htaccess указал такие директивы

```
Options             +Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule  ^http://server1/site1/files  (.*)$  http://server2 /$1 [L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

**В чём проблема** – при редиректе, сервер выдаёт ошибку – 
Server/file.pdf – не найден. Если дописать к пути file://, получив
    file:// Server/file.pdf, 
то файл читается. Хорошо.Теперь если строку

```
RewriteRule  ^http://server1/site1/files  (.*)$  http://server2 /$1 [L], переписать так

RewriteRule  ^http://server1/site1/files  (.*)$  file://server2 /$1 [L], то сайт
```

1.  Не перенаправляет на адрес - file://server2 /$1
2.  Выдат ошибку доступа - Access forbidden!You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. 403 ошибка

Возникает вопрос
Как сделать правильный редирект для любого файла с адреса 
    \server1\site1\files\file.pdf' 
на адрес - 
    \server2\file.pdf